# Insert using npm `mysql` package not working using connection.query method

Tags: mysql

Table Schema Attached:

```
mysql> describe users;
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| username    | varchar(20)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| password    | varchar(128) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| phoneNumber | varchar(128) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| email       | varchar(100) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I am trying to insert into table using npm `mysql` package but unable to insert it.

Inserting through terminal it WORKS perfectly fine:

**INSERT INTO users (username, password,phoneNumber,email) 
                   VALUES 
                   ("user8","userPassword8","8888","user8@gmail.com");**

But When i tried to insert using

```
  connection.query(query, function (err, result) {
                    connection.release();
                    if (!err) {
                        callback(result);
                    } else {
                        console.log(err);
                        callback(null);
                    }
                });
```

By Passing same `Query` to it fails gives following Errro:
Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'phoneNumber' in 'field list'

```
 {
  code: 'ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR',
  errno: 1054,
  sqlMessage: "Unknown column 'phoneNumber' in 'field list'",
  sqlState: '42S22',
  index: 0,
  sql: 'INSERT INTO users (username, password,phoneNumber,email) \n' +
    '                   VALUES \n' +
    '                   ("user8","userPassword8","8888","user8@gmail.com")'
}
```

Comment: most likely you are connected to the wrong database.

Comment: @GarrGodfrey, No if that would be an issue. I should not be able to run `SELECT * FROM users` this query too. :)

Comment: did you just add phoneNumber column? Does phoneNumber show up when you run the SELECT through connector? Maybe you need to commit change to table from command line.